# Pointing Emacs to LaTeX under zsh (for org-latex-export-to-pdf)

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, path

After moving to `zsh` and installing
[MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/),
I can run `pdflatex` fine from the Terminal.

```
$ which pdflatex
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```

I copy that location, itself a soft link

```
  /Library/tex/texbin:
  lrwxr-xr-x   /Library/tex/texbin/ -> ../.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin
```

(which presumably will ultimately lead to
`/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin`)
to my `.emacs`

```
(setq shell-file-name "zsh")

(setq exec-path
      (append exec-path
              '(
                "/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk/"
                )))
```

Yet when running the <kbd>C-c C-e l o</kbd> Org export-to-latex dance, I get

```
zsh:1: command not found: latexmk
```

Comment: That `exec-path` is used for Emacs, not `zsh`.

Comment: @shynur .. and it is indeed Emacs that is looking for `latexmk`. I don't see your point.

Comment: **zsh**:1: `command not found: latexmk`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(setenv "PATH"
        (concat
         "/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk/" path-separator
         (getenv "PATH")))
```

Perhaps `PATH` can be inherited from Emacs when process `zsh` is created.

Comment: +1 - Even better, Emacs would inherit PATH from whoever started it and you wouldn't have to mess with PATH *in* Emacs. But GUIs have tended to make that more difficult than it was when everything was started from a login shell.